# Synonym request for tag [animations], proposed synonym [easing]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonyms

### Synonym Request

I came across this question [screen-transition-effect-like-in-final-fantasy-games](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226919/screen-transition-effect-like-in-final-fantasy-games) where OP makes their custom easing function in order to smoothly transition a color over an image. I did not find any tag that suited so I created a new tag [easing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/easing).

Usage guidance:

> *Easing functions specify the rate of change of a parameter over time. Use this tag when you are using a function to transition the state of
>   an object over a period of time.*

I did, however, found another tag [animation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/995) afterwards.

Usage guidance:

> *For questions related to graphical animations. This includes, but is not limited to sliding, tweening, rotating and resizing of shapes.*

I feel these two tags are closely related. The difference is that an easing function is not limited to graphical animations. I do believe they relate closely enough to be deemed synonyms.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No

I don't think this solves anything.

1. Maybe I'm different to most as I normally pick well known categories and groups. Think [math] rather than [binomial expansion].
2. [There are not many easing questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=easing+animation+is%3Aquestion). <sub>(I had to add a second search term because otherwise it comes back with "ease" which isn't what we're searching for.)</sub>

   Most of the questions seem to be because they inculcated a CSS easing parameter. Where people will probably think CSS 3 animations way before easing.

Comment: If, as you say, _animations_ is the most common name for this type of smoothing, there would indeed be no need for a synonym.

Comment: On top of that, I don't think they're similar enough. Sounds like you can do easing without animation.

Comment: @Mast Yeah, [looks like that's right](https://easings.net/).